# When can Task.Delay throw an ObjectDisposedException?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

According to the documentation, Task.Delay can throw a ObjectDisposedException is the token is disposed.

However, I can't find anything on the CancellationToken that would indicate it is disposed.

Furthermore, disposing the CancellationTokenSource does not cause Task.Delay can throw a ObjectDisposedException.

So what can cause Task.Delay throw an ObjectDisposedException?

Reference: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5fb80297e082b8d6,references

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs,181

Answer (score 3):

Here is a C# code sample that attempts to reproduce the documented behavior:

```cs
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cts.Dispose();
    await Task.Delay(200, cts.Token); // System.ObjectDisposedException
```

Actually it is not the `Task.Delay` that throws, but the attempt to access the `Token` property of the disposed `CancellationTokenSource`. So no, I didn't manage to reproduce the documented behavior either.

Comment: I've tried this snippet and it doesn't throw any exception for me in a netcoreapp2.2, 3.0 or full framework console apps. Are you doing anything else that might illustrate the expected exception?

Comment: @JSteward you are right, I messed up. I updated my answer.