# How do I avoid Task.Delay (in a Timer's Elapsed method) throwing a NullReferenceException, the second time?

Tags: c#, android, timer, maui

I'm trying to take pictures using a timer in a .Net Maui app. I have the pictures working just fine, and can get 5-10 pictures on the first run of the timer, but not on a second call to the timer method. Running the "StartTimer" method (in the code below) more than once throws "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" on the `Task.Delay` call or subsequent firings of a `System.Timers.Timer` event. This crashes the app, even though I have `try...catch` blocks.

I've also tried using a `System.Threading.Timer`, but that never fires.

I know [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58666114/when-can-task-delay-throw-an-objectdisposedexception) the exception happens. Well, sort of. Even if I don't include a `CancellationToken` or if I create a new token, it still throws the error.

I'm using the [Camera.Maui](https://github.com/hjam40/Camera.MAUI) NuGet plugin for the camera functions, if that matters. If I could get the `AutoSnapShot` functionality to work, I probably wouldn't need an answer here, but that's [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76485723/how-do-i-use-the-camera-maui-autosnapshot-option).

This is a .Net 7 Maui app targeting Android API 32. I've only tested this in Android so far, but I've tested it in both `Release` and `Debug` modes on real devices running API versions 28, 31, and 33. The only difference is the API 28 phone takes 1 picture on the second run, then throw the exception, and then takes another picture. Also, the exception doesn't crash the app. This allows me to try running the method multiple times, but each time has the same issue as the second run.

So, what am I doing wrong and/or how do I avoid the `NullReferenceException`?

### Code

The problem code in its own class. I'm calling it from an async method in `MainPage.xaml.cs`. Even if I create a new instance of the class for the "timer" variable, it still throws the `NullReferenceException`. I also changed the class to implement `IDisposable` to try to flush out any residual... whatever that could be affecting the reuse of the class or method, and it still is throwing the exception.

Edit: I've done some more tests with the "timer" variable being local with and without implementing `IDisposable` as well as not using the `using` statement while implementing `IDisposable`, and all tests still throw the `NullReferenceException` when running the "StartTimer" more than once.

```
private readonly TimerTrigger timer = new();

    private async Task<bool> StartCapture()
    {
        try 
        {
            ...
            /*
            using TimerTrigger timer = new();
            */
            timer.StartTimer(quantity, timerDelay);
            ...
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Version 1, with `Task.Delay`:

```
    public async void StartTimer(int quantity, int timerDelay)
    {
        try
        {
            CancellationTokenSource wtoken = new();
            for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // It doesn't matter if I use a token or not, the exception is thrown
                        // await Task.Delay(timerDelay);
                        // await Task.Delay(timerDelay, CancellationToken.None);
                        await Task.Delay(timerDelay, wtoken.Token);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); // This is only hit in API 28
                    }
                }

                // Take picture
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message); // This is never hit
        }
    }
```

Version 2, with a `System.Timers.Timer`:

```
private System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
private int totalQuantity = 0;
private int totalTaken = 0;

    public void StartTimer(int quantity, int timerDelay)
    {
        totalQuantity = quantity;
        aTimer = new()
        {
            Interval = timerDelay
        };

        aTimer.Elapsed += SnapPic;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void SnapPic(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Take picture
            totalTaken++;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); // This is never hit
            EndCapture(false);
        }

        EndCapture(true);
    }
    
    private void EndCapture(bool success)
    {
        if (!success || totalTaken >= totalQuantity)
        {
            aTimer.AutoReset = false;
            aTimer.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Version 3, using `System.Threading.Timer`:

```
private int totalQuantity = 0;
private int totalTaken = 0;

    public void StartTimer(int quantity, int timerDelay)
    {
        AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new(true);
        totalQuantity = quantity;
        using Timer bTimer = new(SnapPic, autoEvent, 0, timerDelay);
        // using Timer bTimer = new(SnapPic, null, 0, timerDelay); // This doesn't run, either
    }

    private void SnapPic(object sender)
    {
        // This method is apparently never run
        try
        {
            // Take picture
            totalTaken++;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            EndCapture(false); // Reusing this method from Version 2
        }

        EndCapture(true); // Reusing this method from Version 2
    }
```

Comment: In your first code snippet you have timer as a readonly variable, are you ever calling into timer again?

Likewise you have using TimerTrigger timer = new ();

Have you tried recently doing TriggerTimer timer = new (); ?

Comment: @iwalkbarefoot, I've left out unrelated uses of the "timer" variable, so it's used in other places prompting the `readonly` attribute. My last test was with the local using/iDisposable version and it's still throwing the `NullReferenceException`. Using "timer" as a local without the "using" also throws the `NullReferenceException`. The same still happens when removing IDisposable from the "TimerTrigger " class and using it as a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some more about timers and playing with another project that uses a `System.Timers.Timer`, I've found a solution.

In Version 2, instead of setting properties to start the timer, I needed to call the `Start` method. And instead of setting properties to end the timer, I needed to call the `Close` and `Dispose` methods.

Old and broken:

```
// Start timer
aTimer.AutoReset = true;
aTimer.Enabled = true;

// End timer
aTimer.AutoReset = false;
aTimer.Enabled = false;
```

New and working:

```
// Start timer, I mean what else would we do, right?
aTimer.Start();

// End timer, obviously... {facepalm}
aTimer.Close();
aTimer.Dispose();
```

And I had to add "totalTaken = 0;" to the "EndCapture" method, if anyone cares. Not resetting this variable caused me to think the problem was still happening when putting "timer" back as a property of the "MainPage" class.

Now I just need to rename that "aTimer" variable. I've already stripped out a bunch of the non-working test code and versions 1 and 3.