# How do I use the Camera.Maui AutoSnapShot option?

Tags: c#, android, maui

I'm trying to take pictures using a timer in a .Net Maui app, but there is a feature of the [Camera.Maui](https://github.com/hjam40/Camera.MAUI) NuGet plugin I'm using that would apparently solve [the issues I'm having](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76485450/task-delay-throwing-nullreferenceexception), but I can't seem to figure out how to use the feature.

There doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to use this feature, except for the minimal mention of the existence of `AutoSnapShot` and related properties. I've tried setting all the properties, yet they don't seem to do anything. I don't see the flash firing, so I'm not convinced there are any pictures being taken.

This is a .Net 7 Maui app targeting Android API 32. I've only tested this in Android so far.

Do I need to start a thread checking "camera.SnapShotStream" for a new image? I'm already having issues with `Task.Delay` (as I linked earlier), so I'm not all that thrilled about potentially moving that problem into this code.

Is there something else am I missing or should be doing differently?

### Code:

The problem code is in a class dedicated to dealing with camera functions, which I'm calling from an async method in `MainPage.xaml.cs`.

```cs
private CameraCapture capture = new();

private async Task<bool> StartCapture()
{
    try 
    {
        ...
        capture.StartTimer(quantity, timerDelay);
        ...
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The relevant methods from the "CameraCapture" class:

```cs
private readonly CameraView camera;
private int pictureQuantity = 0;

public CameraCapture(CameraView cameraView)
{
    camera = cameraView;
}

public void StartTimer(int quantity, int timerDelay)
{
    pictureQuantity = quantity;

    camera.PropertyChanged -= Camera_PropertyChanged;
    camera.PropertyChanged += Camera_PropertyChanged;
    camera.AutoSnapShotFormat = AppPreferences.Settings.Filetype;
    camera.AutoSnapShotSeconds = timerDelay / 1000;
    camera.AutoSnapShotAsImageSource = true;
    camera.TakeAutoSnapShot = true;
}

private void Camera_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // e.PropertyName ends up being stuff like "AutoSnapShotFormat" and "AutoSnapShotSeconds ", 
    // but never "SnapShotStream".
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(camera.SnapShotStream))
    {
        Stream stream = camera.SnapShotStream;
        // Send "stream" to another method to handle the image being captured
        autosnapshotCount++;

        if (autosnapshotCount >= pictureQuantity)
        {
            autosnapshotCount = 0;
            camera.TakeAutoSnapShot = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you read the relevant code, or looked at the sample provided in the repo?

Comment: @Jason, yes, I've read the relevant code from the repo and looked at the "Test" project. Unfortunately, the "Test" doesn't seem to do much with the "AutoSnapShot" feature, other than setting the same values I did. I don't see where it uses the results. I've run it on my API 33 phone, and selecting the "Take Autosnap" checkbox doesn't really seem to do anything other than update one of the pictures once. I see a timer, but the method doesn't seem to do anything. After playing around with it more, I changed the "Autosnap freq" and it finally works, but still no flash so not a good quality pic.

Comment: You might wanna raise a bug and see what the repo owner has to say